# I want to show all the posts for each category

Tags: laravel

I have a database like this
[Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5uzGA.jpg)

My Categories.php

```
public function Subcategory()
{
    return $this -> hasMany('App\Subcategories', 'category_id');
}
```

My Subcategories.php

```
public function Post()
{
    return $this -> hasMany('App\Posts', 'subcategory_id');
}

public function Category()
{
    return $this -> belongsTo('App\Categories', 'category_id');
}
```

My Posts.php

```
public function Subcategory()
{
    return $this -> belongsTo('App\Subcategories', 'subcategory_id');
}
```

I want to take all the posts from each Category, and show them on my "index" page, what should I do?

Comment: Show us what you've tried

Answer (score 1):

You could use this relationship: https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through

Categories.php

```
public function Subcategory()
{
    return $this -> hasMany('App\Subcategories', 'category_id');
}

public function posts()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Posts', 'App\Subcategories');
}
```

Subcategories.php

```
public function Post()
{
    return $this -> hasMany('App\Posts', 'subcategory_id');
}

public function Category()
{
    return $this -> belongsTo('App\Categories', 'category_id');
}
```

Posts.php

```
public function Subcategory()
{
    return $this -> belongsTo('App\Subcategories', 'subcategory_id');
}
```

Then you can call the Categories with their respective Posts like this:

```
Categories::with('posts')->get()
```

**Note:** You should use the standard naming conventions, using Models in singular.. https://webdevetc.com/blog/laravel-naming-conventions